# Why is the Start() method in ViewModel not called after restoring the activity?

Tags: android-activity, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

When the adroid kills the application, after its restoration the method OnCreate() in Activity is called, but the Start() method in ViewModel is not called.

1. Activity is opened.
2. OnCreate() method is called in the Activity.
3. Start() method is called in ViewModel.
4. Minimize the application in the background.
5. Android system kills the application.
6. Open the application.
7. OnCreate() method is called in the Activity.
8. Start() method is not called in ViewModel. -----> Why?

Comment: Could you share your code of Start()?